# If $W(t)$=$r$+$1$/$s$-$t$($1$-$q$/$s$) how can I calculate the probability density function of $W(t)$?

Tags: probability, density-function, function

In this formula t is the time of arrivals (random variable) of vehicles at an intersection and W(t) is estimated delay. How can I develop the probability density function of the vehicle delays given this function?[image: this is delay as a function of arrival time W(t)]

Comment: Since multiplying $-t$ by $1-q/s$ and adding $r+1/s$ to that is a mere change of units (just like multiplying by $9/5$ and adding $32$ converts temperatures Celsius to temperatures Fahrenheit), the only thing you need to figure out is the relationship between the density of $t$ and the density of $-t$.  Perhaps that's equally obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(W(t)\leq w)=P(r + 1/s-T(1-q/s) \leq w) = P(T\geq -(w-r-1/s)/(1-q/s))$

Which gives use $f_W(w)=\frac{d}{dw} (1-F_T(-(w-r-1/s)/(1-q/s)))$

where $F_T$ is the distribution function of $T$, and $f_W$ is the density function of $W$.

You still have to worry about the support and so forth though. If you know the distribution function of $T$ than you know the density of $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I just don't understand why you are using the derivative of w? how did you reach fw(w)?

Comment: The density is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function, by definition. You take the derivative with respect to $w$ because that is your argument in the function. We know the density $f_W(w)=\frac{d}{dw}F_W(w)$, and we know  $F_W(w)=1-(F_T(-(w-r-1/s)/(1-q/s)))$ and we have $F_W(w)=P(W \leq w)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one last thing hope you could help out. If the arrival process is Poisson do I just use the Poisson distribution as FT?

Comment: If the arrival process is poisson, the time to arrival is exponential.

Remember, time is continuous and thus cannot be Poisson (which is discrete).